# How can I tell React Native's *Metro Bundler* to serve files from `./lib/src`?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm working on a React Native project. I got my TypeScript files located in `./src`. This is transpiled to `./lib/`.

E.g `./src/index.ts` ends up in `./lib/src/index.js`.

How can I tell **Metro Bundler** (`npm start`) to serve files from `./lib/src`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

**android/app/build.gradle**

Change line 5

```
  1 apply plugin: "com.android.application"
  2
  3 import com.android.build.OutputFile
  4
  5 project.ext.react = [
  6   entryFile: "src/index.js"
  7 ]
  8
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhms, this is a tad late... but what you might want to do is:

1. Change your `./index.js` to just `import "./lib`
2. Change your tsconfig.json `outDir` property to `"./lib"` (that way you avoid having the `./lib/src` path.

That's what I do with my projects.